# Comparing two objects in a List<> and assign them with new value

Tags: c#

How do I compare two object in a list? The list contains objects with two properties Number and description. The numbers are such as CC2 and NS1, and the description are Abcd, acd, …

The list's member: CC1 Abcd, NU15 Abcd, CC2 Acd, NS1 Abd, CC21 Abd

```
string start = "NU15 Abcd";
string end = "NS1 Abd";

string startletters = string.Empty;
string startnumbers = string.Empty;

string endletters = string.Empty;
string endnumbers = string.Empty;

foreach (char c in start)
{
    if (Char.IsLetter(c))
    {
        startletters += c;
    }
    if (Char.IsNumber(c))
    {
        startnumbers += c;
    }
}
foreach (char c in end)
{
    if (Char.IsLetter(c))
    {
        endletters += c;
    }
    if (Char.IsNumber(c))
    {
        endnumbers += c;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < Program.file.Count; i++)
{
    if (startname == Program.file[i].Desc && start != Program.file[i].Number)
    { 
        start = Program.file[i].Number;      
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to check if start has another number that start with NS, similarly with end, to check if Abd has another number so that both will match(both are starting with CC). Keep in mind that the value of start and end is in this format but not the same value as i assigned because they are input, the value above are just for reference. So the result will be

```
start = "CC1 Abcd"; end = "CC21 Abd";
```

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind you compression but to create your custom compression you need to implement [`IComparable`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/320727/how-to-use-the-icomparable-and-icomparer-interfaces-in-visual-c)

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/nl-be/help/320727/how-to-use-the-icomparable-and-icomparer-interfaces-in-visual-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood from your question:

```
//This will get you the first two characters of the string
string subS = start.Substring(0,2);
string subE = end.Substring(0,2);

//Do the comparison
if (subS == subE)
{
//your logic
}
else 
{
//another logic
}
```

Comment: so subS = NU and subE = NS, so how do I change both into CC without hardcoding it because subS and subE are actually input, I put the value there as reference of what it could be.